# Blender 3.6 transparency issue

Tags: transparency, hair, blend-files

I have problem with character hair. In Blender it looks fine and perfact but when I export glb it becomes like other image. I tried blending mode both alpha blend and alpha hashed.

How to solve this problem?(blender,cc4,glb)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You say it yourself - in Blender it looks fine, the problem occurs when you export it to GLB. Blend modes like _Alpha Hashed_ and _Alpha Blend_ are Blender specific and are not exported to other file formats. You have to find out how the software where you want to use the file handles alpha transparency, but this site is for problems within Blender, not other software. The answer you'll find here: [fbx export - why are there are no materials or textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/) though asked for FBX and UE4 is applicable to other file formats and programs as well.

Comment: thank you for your time it helps a lot

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)